# Unique alphanumeric between 5-11 characters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alphanumeric

I have seen several approaches to generate a unique alphanumeric, but most of the approaches specify a particular length.

What would be a good way to get a unique alphanumeric associated with a model which length has to be between 5 and 11?

I was trying with this approach:

```
Array.new(8){[*'0'..'9', *'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z'].sample}.join
```

But the size is limited to 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your example by using rand:

```
Array.new(rand(5..11)) { [*'0'..'9', *'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z'].sample }.join
```

Also you can use [SecureRandom](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html), but it can't generate string with only A-Z, a-z, 0-9 symbols. Maybe you can choose any other sequence. I prefer urlsafe_base64 or hex:

```
require 'securerandom'

SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(rand(5..11)) #result may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, “-”
SecureRandom.hex(rand(5..11)) #result may contain 0-9 and a-f
```